# Gwas analysis studies using the result of differential analysis

Tags: gwas

I want to do a GWAS analysis using the differentially expressed genes that I got from a differential analysis. The purpose is the identification of biomarkers.

It's my first time using GWAS, can you please suggest to me a pipeline to use?

Comment: If you are looking for biomarkers, why not look at all genes? There will be a lot more information there.

Comment: ok thank u,  so we have to use all genes as phenotypes.
it's my first time using GWAS, can you suggest me a pipeline to use.

Comment: @MaximilianPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on recent packages but I would suggest using [Matrix eQTL](http://www.bios.unc.edu/research/genomic_software/Matrix_eQTL/) for purposes of the statistical analysis.

As mentioned in the comments I think that it is worth testing *all* transcripts for eQTL associations. This will additionally give some idea of the false discovery rate. It is possible that testing "candidate gene" differentially expressed genes will lead to a lot of false positives relative to the background level of associations.